# How to open a large csv with a list of urls and crawl through those?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a large csv that is on my local machine that only contains a list of urls no other columns I want to crawl and extract a certain css element from each of those urls. I have completed a test of that doing a sample of just a one off start url by not looking at the csv. I can't figure out how to open up a large csv with like a million urls in it to have scrapy go through each one and scrape it and then go to the next.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import stkscrapeItem

class stkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'stkscrape'
start_urls = [
    'https://www.exampleurl.com'
]

def parse(self, response):

    items = stkscrapeItem()

    contriburl = response.css(".b_q_e a::attr(href)").extract()

    items['contriburl'] = contriburl
    yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

### I just typed this directly here, so can have typos.

But should be pretty close to what you are expecting

Just to make it perform better, you can split the millions CSV file into chunks using pandas:

#### create_files.py

```
import pandas as pd
counter = 0
for df in pd.read_csv("your_file_with_urls.csv", chunksize=100000):
    df.to_csv(f"input_{counter}.csv", index=False)
    counter += 1
```

This generates some files at the same location.

Now in the same location as the `scrapy.cfg` file create a file `main.py` with the following:

#### main.py

```
from glob import glob
from scrapy import cmdline


for each_file in glob("input_*.csv"):
    cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl your_spider".split() + ["-a", each_file])
```

This way we are sending each small file's name to the spider's constructor (the **init**.py function)

In your `your_spider`, receive the argument `each_file` as follow:

#### your_spider.py

```
def YourSpiderName(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self, each_file='', **kwargs):
        self.start_urls =  set(pd.read_csv("path_to/each_file")["URL_COLUMN"].tolist())
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # python3
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. So I did the following:

#1) I created create_files.py with what you had but changed "your_file_with_urls.csv" and changed it to urls.csv that is in the same folder that urls.csv is the csv with million urls in it

#2) I created the main.py exactly as you have the code in the same folder as the scrapy.cfg

Comment: #3) The spider.py file is where I am getting a syntax error now " /spiders/sstkscrape_spider.py", line 7
    def sstkscrape(scrapy.Spider):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Do you know what I have done wrong by chance?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? But may be you should play around or ask another question. It doesn't fit with this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, I have submitted a new question with all of my details and environment. Thank you for your help.